# How to convert JSON to array in PHP?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

While receiving the following JSON

```
{ "phone": [ "123", "456", "789"]}
```

in PHP I try to get this (displayed with `print_r`):

```
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 456 [2] => 789 )
```

Therefore I tried to use the following code, without success:

```
if (isset($_GET["phone"])) {
    //Decode Json
    $values = json_decode($_GET['phone'], true);
    print_r($values);
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
    }...
```

How can I receive and convert this JSON in the requested array?

It's working fine while the JSON is defined in the php code. Then I get an associative array. In my mind the problem might be in the java (android) code because the $_GET['phone'] should work in php:

```
 ArrayList<String> paramsstring = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> paramstodb = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
 contacts = aa.toArray(new String[aa.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        paramsstring.add(contacts[i]);}

    paramstodb.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", paramsstring.toString()));

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_user, "GET", paramstodb);
```

Maybe php receives another format of that JSON? The GET request should not be the problem, because the JSON is not very long.

Comment: This should work fine! Please show us your **full** code

Comment: `$array = json_decode($_GET['phone'], true);
    $values=$array['phone'];`

Comment: I edited the android code which is sending the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump`ing the decoded JSON object results in:

the object version

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["phone"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "456"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "789"
  }
}
```

the associative array version:

```
array(1) {
  ["phone"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "456"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "789"
  }
}
```

Which is exactly what it should return. 
See here: http://ideone.com/CDBvGQ

Since it's a nested array, that foreach won't work as you expected, try this instead:

```
foreach ($values['phone'] as $key => $value) {
```

See it fully working here: http://ideone.com/QG3uH6

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you get the json values in `$_GET["phone"]`

```
if (isset($_GET["phone"])) {
    //Decode Json
    $array = json_decode($_GET['phone'], true); 
    $values=$array['phone'];

    print_r($values);
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
    }
 }
```